# RunTimeException What's the cause?

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, jpa, runtimeexception

I try to build this jpa project but running into the same error. 
I updated, changed everything still nothing. What am I missing? I only use EclipseLink (JPA 2.0) in the libaries. NetBeans IDE 7.2.

```
An annotation processor threw an uncaught exception.
Consult the following stack trace for details.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception [EclipseLink-25008] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
Exception Description: A descriptor with default root element {http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence}persistence was not found in the project
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor.process(CanonicalModelProcessor.java:407)
    .
    .
    .

    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:541)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-25008] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
Exception Description: A descriptor with default root element {http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence}persistence was not found in the project
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException.noDescriptorWithMatchingRootElement(XMLMarshalException.java:129)
    .
    .
    .

    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.objects.PersistenceUnitReader.<init>(PersistenceUnitReader.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor.process(CanonicalModelProcessor.java:376)
    ... 49 more
C:\Users\drhorvath57\Desktop\nyomt\PizzaJPA\PizzaJPA\nbproject\build-impl.xml:926: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\drhorvath57\Desktop\nyomt\PizzaJPA\PizzaJPA\nbproject\build-impl.xml:268: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="PizzaJPAPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>logic.entity.Pizza</class>
    <class>logic.entity.Topping</class>
    <class>logic.entity.Combination</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/PizzaJPA"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="APP"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="APP"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are either missing your persistence.xml or it is malformed. Check out the [example in eclipselink's site](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/JPAConfigure) if you are unsure about how to create the file.

******EDIT******

If you're using Netbeans you should check your IDE documentation about how to generate the persistence.xml file instead of creating it yourself.

Comment: I tried that but still nothing. Funny thing is it worked at the beginning, but now refuse to build.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using a persistence.xml file with [schema version 2.1](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/persistence/index.html), however making use of the JPA API version 2.0. So, update to newer API or change your persistence.xml file to conform with the JPA 2.0 version.